# What is UncaughtExceptionPreHandler in Java

Tags: java, android, exception

I was looking at android platform source code and found this commit:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/addbf9015a65ed7704a4fc22f36380dd153698da

As I understood it fixes the issue of logging app crashes for apps that register global exception handler with Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)
but I would like to understand how it does that.

Main thing I don't get here is what the method Thread.setUncaughtExceptionPreHandler(...) does since I cannot find any documentation for it, it is not available on the Thread class when I try to use it from the code and it is not even in the source code of the Android Thread class.

To clarify: I know how to use setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler and that is not my question here. My question is about this setUncaughtExceptionPreHandler (note the Pre word) method which I have never seen before and can't find any documentation on it.